# Pannier Bags for Burley Kazoo

Tags: panniers

I have a [burley kazoo](https://burley.com/product/kazoo/) trail-a-bike, which my five year-old and I are really enjoying. When not trailing my 5yo, I can easily put my Arkel pack onto the burley rack, but its attachment points don't quite fit when the kazoo is also attached. I'd like to do some bike-packing with my 5yo and thus need to attach panniers while he's on the back.

So I was wondering if there are any Kazoo riders out there who have found a decent bag that fits around the Kazoo's attachment point? Is this even an ok idea? Are there other suggestions for how else I might carry gear and a tail-a-bike?

EDIT: I wrote Burley about this. They said (a) their panniers will fit, but (b) they don't recommend having a kid on the kazoo at the same time as panniers, so I should get front racks instead.

Comment: You could possibly use a rack designed for a 20" wheel folding bike on the Kazoo, and put panniers on that. You would need to fiddle around with P-clips because the frame doesn't have rack mounts, but at least a 5yo's feet won't need as much clearance as an adults - on the other hand the saddle would be much lower than an adult on a folding bike.
(When I had a trailerbike, it was seatpost mounting, so I could use panniers, but that does have disadvantages. The old Islabike rack mounts left the side rails free - http://www.hembrow.eu/personal/trailerbikes.html)

Comment: How about a front rack?

Comment: This question might benefit from a photo from the side, showing how your tow bike and your trailer bike go together.  Ideally a clear, well-lit, high resolution photo, probably in sunlight with a contrasting background if possible.

Comment: @Criggie Yes, I should have done that.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, I think that's what I'll end up doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll struggle to find panniers that will fit that rack with the trailer attached.

It's just possible a seatpost mounted pack would work, but the clearance looks tight.
[image: seatpack]

Comment: How well it fits well depend on the frame and parent sizes but this would be a very reasonable approach

Answer (score 4):

Along with a seatpost-mounted bag and front panniers, you might consider a frame bag.  Depending on your frame geometry, it can carry a surprisingly large volume of gear.
[image: Frame bag picture]

Comment: Thanks you, I will!

Answer (score 2):

My Axiom touring packs fit the Kazoo rack perfectly.  My 5 year old and I just went on a 38 mile ride with two fully loaded panniers and no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Do you know which model? Or can you post a photo?